# QueryselectorAll invalid CSS Selector in Electron, but working in Browser

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, electron

I have a form with several columns with inputs. There are also empty columns and columns with only disabled inputs.

So i want to get all columns with enabled inputs and ignore the rest. I use

`container.querySelectorAll('.c-col-1:has(input:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled))')`

I went to check the selector with an online CSS validator [here](http://csslint.net/)

It points to the colon of the first `:not` saying it expects a right parantheses or in cases of enumerations a comma. Even when i tried `.c-col-1:has(input, button)` same error occurs, it expects a comma or right parantheses where the first comma is.

The thing is that when I use my app in the browser everything seems to work just fine and I get the right columns.

But my app running as Electron App breaks, throwing querySelectorAll failed because of invalid selector.

Comment: Does Electron somehow not require delimiters for text literals ...? Or should this perhaps be `container.querySelectorAll('.c-col-1:has(input:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled))')`

Comment: May be `:has` is not supported.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, i missed the '', updated my question

Comment: Which version of electron are you using? What chromium version does it use?

Comment: @SalmanA 11.0.3

Comment: @SalmanA but also the fact, that the css validator says, it´s invalid, although :has() is a valid css pseudo class. keeps wondering me

Comment: okay, has:() passes the validator, i just needed to also give properties in curly brackets

Comment: `:has` has been added recently (don't know exactly when) so it will only be recognized in most recent versions of browsers. Wikipedia says electron js 11 uses chromium 87 and that definitely does not support (or understand) this pseudo class.

Comment: @SalmanA thank you for your input. where did you find that information? do you think updating electron could help?

Comment: I am not sure if updating would help, its just that I recently had some complains about website looking bad in iPhone 6, which I did not have access to, so I downloaded older version of Chromium to match the version used in iPhone 6 Safari and turns out it was the `:has` selector which did not work in Chromium 67. I am only guessing that it is the same issue.